# UWP independent scrollviews

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, scrollviewer

The idea is to have a one column with lots of elements in a scrollable listview and a second column (not scrollable) with small details. The problem is that entire page is scrolling and as a result the second column is out of the view.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Scrollviewer x:Name="scrollviewer" Grid.Column="0">
            <Listview ItemsSource={...} ItemTemplate={...} />
        </Scrollviewer>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <...>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've tried to link window height to scrollviewer height with SizeChanged event (`scrollviewer.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height`), and it works kind of until I scroll for a little bit and then it crashes with an error "Layout cycle detected".
I think it supposed to be very common scenario and I am missing something here. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: without checking, set a rowdefiniton because normally a grid will take all available space, so that the column will ALWAYS expand to Content size, you have to delimit thisby seeting Heigh="*" or a static value

Comment: FYI, generally *do not* place  ListView inside a ScrollViewer. It breaks the performance handling ListView carries out and can cause massive layout costs. ListView contains it's own internal ScrollViewer, so scrolls by default without you specifying anything.

Comment: Setting a rowdefiniton didn't help, with Heigh="*" the whole page is still scrolling, with the static value it works but I want a column to fill entire window height. And if I settting value to window height in code behind in OnSizeChanged event, rapid resizing window crashes application.

Comment: @user2814036 Why use a `ListView` within a `ScrollViewer`? A `ListView` on itself already has a `ScrollViewer`. Furthermore I copied you XAML, added a `TextBlock` to your `StackPanel` with some filler text and added a method that fills the `ListView` with 500 items. I was not able to recreate your problem.

Comment: @Leander I added gif how my page is scrolling. I know that Listview has its own scrollviewer I tried both, regardless with or without it I can't make only left column to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t reproduce your issue.
You could check the following sample to compare your code.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
..>

<Grid>
    <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Left"  ItemInvoked="NavigationView_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems >
            <NavigationViewItem Content="A" x:Name="A" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="B" x:Name="B" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="C" x:Name="C" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void NavigationView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.InvokedItemContainer;
        switch (item.Name)
        {
            case "B":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                break;
        }
    }
```

BlankPage1.xaml:

```
<Page
..>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fruits}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Fruit">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind price}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
 
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="yyyyyyyyygggg"/>
        <TextBlock Text="hkcsduhgfuhiualhfijht" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

BlankPage1.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>()
        {
            new Fruit(){name="apple",price=12},
            new Fruit(){name="peach",price=15},
            new Fruit(){name="pear",price=8},
            new Fruit(){name="banana",price=31},
            new Fruit(){name="grape",price=5},
            .......
            // Add items that fill the entire page
           new Fruit(){name="banana",price=31},
            new Fruit(){name="grape",price=5},
            new Fruit(){name="apple",price=12}
                   
        };
      
    }
}
public class Fruit
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I found my mistake. I had my frame inside another scrollviewer in NavigationView. Now it works. Thank you.